# Samsung A21S support USB-C to HDMI?

Tags: samsung, hdmi

I buyed a USB-C to HDMI device and it didnt work, so i thought the problem is the device and tryed to get a refund.

I have no other device capable of testing it and i searched in the entire Internet about it but found nothing.

I found something about HML and my device does not support it, but some people said that the HDMI works even without the device supporting HML.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung flagship devices support it - not all. Check the lists at [mhltech.org](https://www.mhltech.org/devices.aspx?tid=1) and [everybodywiki.com](https://en.everybodywiki.com/List_of_devices_with_video_output_over_USB-C#Smartphones). I cannot find the A21s or its model alias SM-A217F there.